# How can I converting (multiple) categorical features into dummy set in a single process

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I have a frame with a lot of categorical features (50+) that I want to convert into 0/1 buckets (one-hot-encoded). In python, is it possible to convert them all without having to do each one separately? I have tried One-Hot-Encoder. They are all string variables.

Comment: What do you mean by each one seperately?

Answer (score 0):

In the `pandas` package, you can use `get_dummies` ([reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html)):

```
import pandas as pd

pd.get_dummies(df[['string_column_a', 'string_column_b']])
```